# SQL: Select distinct from two columns where only column2 is different

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble generating a query (and I've looked online and SO and can't find it). I'm wanting to select distinct two columns where only the second column is different.

Ideally, it would look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT colA, colB
FROM table
GROUP BY colA, colB
```

with the condition that colB is only different

For example, here's what I'd like it to do, in case what I said is not clear

```
colA | colB
-----------
abc  |1
abc  |2
abd  |1
abf  |1
xyz  |1
asd  |2
```

*SQL MAGIC*

```
calA | colB
-----------
abc  |1
abc  |2
```

It basically removes the rows where the `colB` is is different.

Thanks!

Comment: use count and then do when count >1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `JOIN` solution is:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT a.*
 FROM table a
 JOIN table b
    ON  a.colA  = b.colA
    AND a.colB != b.colB
```

Comment: This will add duplicates if you have more than two values for colB.

Comment: Whoops! Missed that! But even so, self join performance would be brutal with a lot of records.

Comment: As would `GROUP BY ` & `HAVING`, but self joins aren't always brutal, MySQL can optimize it with the right keys. (`INDEX(colA,colB)` comes to mind...)

Comment: Nah, it would still be brutal, because it starts with the square of the number of rows. `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` is much better.

Comment: @AlvinThompson: having a few million rows here does not much to dent my mysql server, especially when colA & colB are not ordered. Can you post some benchmarking?

Comment: Let's try math, first: a few million rows squared is something like **9 trillion** rows it would have to start from. You must have one beefy server...

Comment: Let's try relation databases & keys first. Pessimistic brute force isn't what MySQL does.

Comment: None of which will help much if there actually are millions of rows with repeat colB's.

Comment: I await your benchmark results at my pleasure. Numbers speak louder than words.

Comment: It's been running on a DB I have with about 10 million rows for about 13 minutes now. I'm betting it will fail rather than complete.

Comment: A fine thing to notice BTW is that your derived table in your subquery has no index.....

Comment: I also ran that query on my DB. Less then 5 seconds.

Comment: Although in all honestly, this is a PostGreSQL server. Maybe MySQL has some miracle technology which makes it faster...

Comment: Run it on a MySQL server then. Postgres _is_ better at1 some area's, MySQL @ other, maybe it can still use an index on `colA`. MySQL cannot use an index in colA in a derived table. My numbers are quite different than yours apparently, but as this is a MySQL question.... (Fwiw: mine runs here on 0.12 seconds, yours @ 4min33) Seeded 1 mln records with colA  between 0 & 99999, colB the same.

Comment: **CORRECTION:** My query ran in less than **50** seconds.

Comment: I'm not going to re-prove what I've already proven. It also should be obvious that that query will never be as efficient due to the self join. End of discussion.

Comment: @Alvin: go forth and find a MySQL server, I am _not_ kidding you about a wildly different result.

Comment: It's amazing that your MySQL server manages to collect a result set with millions of rows in 0.12 seconds, according to you. I can do a `SELECT ID FROM FOO` on our production server and not get results like that...

Comment: 1 mln records, only selecting those which have multiple colB's here are about due to random seeding about 30% (roughly 300k), and I work local so no network involved. But I'll make you a deal, I'm going to set up PostgreSQL here to see what's so fancy about your query there, 'cause I sure as hell get different results in MySQL.

Comment: That's still quite impossible, even if MySQL cached your statement.

Comment: Well, if you don't trust my numbers I don't see a way we'll ever see eye to eye about this. I'm seeding a postgresql thingamayig now, and I'll see what that yields, but if you're unwilling to check in MySQL, well, I think we're done with each other then....

Comment: Reading up on the material though, a great contributor to the difference (seeding still going on, so not confirmed here yet), is that [MySQL has index-only scans](http://mysqlha.blogspot.nl/2010/11/how-are-index-only-scans-implemented-in.html) (and with both `colA` & `colB` in the index and no other columns selected that will happen), whereas [PostgreSQL apparently does not](http://rhaas.blogspot.nl/2010/11/index-only-scans.html)

Answer (score 3):

Based on your sample output, it looks like you're only including `colA` values if they have multiple, differing `colB` values. You can do that like this:

```
SELECT colA, colB FROM table
WHERE colA IN (
  SELECT colA
  FROM table
  GROUP BY colA
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT colB) > 1)
```

Comment: Yes, this is the wording I was looking for. This is exactly right. I will except asap. Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad it worked! I can understand how hard it was to word this; I had plenty of trouble myself :)

Comment: But this doesn't give the output @ChristopherBales was looking for. It gives him the counts instead.

Comment: Thanks Alvin - you're absolutely right. That was supposed to be the inner query; I completely left off the outer part. I'll edit in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
SELECT MIN(colA) AS colA, colB
FROM table
GROUP BY colB
```

or

```
SELECT MAX(colA) AS colA, colB
FROM table
GROUP BY colB
```

but your question is somewhat unclear, so I'm not sure this is what you are asking for, or not.

Answer (score 1):

To get the column A values with multiple B valuates, you can use a `group by` with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT colA
FROM table
GROUP BY colA
having min(colB) <> max(colB)
```

Then you need to `join` this back in to the original query, somehow.  Here is an approach using `in`:

```
select *
from table
where colA in (SELECT colA
               FROM table
               GROUP BY colA
               having min(colB) <> max(colB)
              )
```

You can also replace the `having` comparison with `having count(distinct colB) > 1`, but I think the `min()`/`max()` comparison would generally perform better.

Comment: In your query you have grouped by `ColB` so won't `MIN(ColB)` always equal `MAX(ColB)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
select colA, colB
from table
where colA in (select colA from table group by colA having count(*) > 1)
order by colA, colB
```